# How to delete store specific url rewrite?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using following to delete a url rewrite

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath($requestPath)->delete();
```

How to make it specific to a store only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following to achieve required :

```
  $storeId = 2;

  Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId($storeId)
->loadByRequestPath($requestPath)->delete();
```